# Show profile to the owner only and not to other users in view

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

I want to show this view to the owner of the object not other logged in userse. Is this possible with the UserPasseTestMixin i class view? And hos should i do this?

this is not login related so please dont write about login related information thx

thx

````
class UserDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DetailView):
    model = User
    slug_field = "pk"
    slug_url_kwarg = "pk"
   
   
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
        return self.render_to_response(context)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to implement a `slug_field` or anything if you only want to show this to the owner. You can simply return the logged in use in `get_object`:

```
class UserDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = User
    
    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.request.user
```

The url can thus look like:

```
path('profile/', UserDetailView.as_view(), name='profile')
```

*without* a primary key, since the `User` object is fully determined by the logged in user.

Comment: Why make it simple? Ive been at it for hours and Willem comes to the rescure. U are a genius . Thx it worked like a charm